# BufferedReader & FileReader read() Performance - Large Text File

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm using the following 2 pieces of codes to read a large file.

This using a `FileReader`:

```
File file = new File("/Users/Desktop/shakes.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

int ch;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) ch);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And the following using a `BufferedReader`:

```
File file = new File("/Users/Desktop/shakes.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

int ch;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char) ch);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Going by the documentation for `BufferedReader`:

> It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders. Without buffering, each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

Given this documentation and the default buffer size of 8192 of the BufferedReader class, shouldn't the overall time for reading the file with BufferedReader be quicker? Currently, both pieces of code run in ~3000ms on my machine. However, if I use 'readLine' in the BufferedReader, the performance substantially improves (~200ms).

Thoughts on something that I'm missing? Is it not expected that even with the 'read()' method, BufferedReader should give a better performance than reading from FileReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `BufferedReader` is indeed faster than using just FileReader.

I executed your code on my machine, with the following text file https://norvig.com/big.txt (6MB).

- The initial result shows roughly the same time. About 17 seconds each.
- However, this is because `System.out.print()` is a bottleneck (within the loop). Without print, the result is 4 times faster with `BufferedReader`. 200ms vs 50ms. (Compare it to 17s before)

In other words, don't use `System.out.print()` when benchmarking.

**Example**

An improved benchmark could look like this using `StringBuilder`.

```
File file = new File("/Users/Desktop/shakes.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

int ch;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
    //System.out.print((char) ch);
    sb.append((char) ch);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(sb);
```

The above code provides the same output but performs much faster. It will accurately show the difference in speed when using a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer J.A.P! I modified my code to get rid of the System.out and BufferedReader is indeed consistently better than the FileReader and by almost the same factor every time as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Thoughts on something that I'm missing?

It should be faster to read a file a character at a time from a `BufferedReader` than a `FileReader`.  (By orders of magnitude!)  So I suspect that problem is in your benchmarks.

1. Your benchmark is measuring both reading the file, and writing it to standard output.  So basically, your performance figures will be distorted by the overheads of *writing* the file.  And if your output is being written to a "console", then those overheads include the overheads of painting characters to the screen ... and scrolling.
2. Your benchmark takes no account of vm startup overheads.
3. Your benchmark doesn't (obviously) take the effect of file caching.  (The first time a file is read, it will be read from disc.  If you read it again soon afterwards, you *may* be reading from a copy of the file cached in memory by the operating system.  That will be faster.)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. You are right and I was able to verify it as well by removing the System.out statements.